# Seeing other files when using Ruby on Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using the RoR asset pipeline by calling `//= require_tree .` in my application.js file. When I load the page and go to network developer tools in Firefox I see network calls to all of the js files instead of just the application.js file. I'm pretty sure the application.js is compressed and ready to use but is it normal to see network calls to all the other files even though they should already be the application.js file?

Comment: It's ok for dev mode - all required js assets are included as separate files. It's convenient to debug in which file error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the intended behavior. You can change it if you want in `development.rb` by flipping this setting to `false`

```
# Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
# This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
# number of complex assets.
config.assets.debug = true
```